# Check if at least one Textbox is not null within control

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am trying to check if there is at least one `Textbox` is not null as shown below but that condition will be true if all `Textbox`are not null not only one at least

```
foreach (TextBox cont in GB_Search.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cont.Text))
    {
        // at least one control 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I have to fill all `textbox` to make that condition false but that not important 
it enough for me to fill one `textbox`

Comment: the default value of the `TextBox.Text` property is an empty string, so unless you've explicitly set it as `null` why would you want to check for nullity? are you asking to check whether at least one  `TextBox.Text` is empty?  or are you asking whether a `TextBox` instance has a state of null?

Comment: @Aominè thank you for the information your provide i was not know that 
actually I am checking if it is empty I have not set for null at all

Comment: @Aominè thanks ill check it ... your information was so much helpful

Comment: @sam this is only documented for the `System.Windows.Controls`  TextBox and not for the `System.Windows.Forms` TextBox but i've provided both solutions anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.Windows.Controls TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.text?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Controls_TextBox_Text)

The default value of the `TextBox.Text` property is an empty string, so unless you've explicitly set it as `null` I don't see why you'd want to check for nullity.

You're most likely looking to see if any of the `TextBox.Text` is empty like this:

```
var result = GB_Search.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                               .Any(textBox => textBox.Text.Length == 0);
```

or if there is any non-empty:

```
var result = GB_Search.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                               .Any(textBox => !(textBox.Text.Length == 0));
```

Note - I've specifically used the `Length` property of the `TextBox` to check if it's empty as opposed to `String.IsNullOrEmpty`, this is simply because as mentioned above `TextBox.Text` is by default an empty string and as you've mentioned in the comments section under your post you're not explicitly setting it to `null`, thus there's no need to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` as it performs a redundant check that you don't need.

[System.Windows.Forms TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.text?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_Text)

Looking to see if any of the `TextBox.Text` is null or empty:

```
var result = GB_Search.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                               .Any(textBox => string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text));
```

or if there is any non null and non empty:

```
var result = GB_Search.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                               .Any(textBox => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text));
```

Comment: what if there are white-spaces in the TextBox ?

Comment: Then use String.IsNullOrWhitespace. String.IsNullOrEmpty doesn’t handle that.

Comment: to be on safe side we always use  latter option, as we can never trust user input :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq for this.

The following will check that at least one should not be null and will return `true` if  at least one text box contains value in it:

```
var oneHasValue = GB_Search.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                    .Any(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text));
```

and the following would return `true` if all are not null or empty:

```
var allContainValue = GB_Search.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                      .All(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text));
```